# Unable to boot Windows 7 after Ubuntu 12.10 update

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, windows, ssd

I have a Dell Vostro 3360 with 500GB+32GB SSD and I've installed dual boot Windows 7/Ubuntu 12.10. Everything worked fine till I upgraded the kernel version as I noticed that Windows 7 from GRUB menu disappeared.

I've tried several ways and hours to solve it but, I cannot make Windows 7 boot again.

Boot-repair (from Ubunutu or LiveCD) didn't solve the issue as it seems it doesn't see the Windows installation. Here it is the pastebin:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1669486/

I even added manually the entries using Grub Customizer to boot directly from /sda3, but the error returned is "bootmngr is missing". Using a windows 7 recovery disk, the Startup Recovery option doesn't solve anything. Also, it doesn't see the previous Windows installation. The windows partition is already active (marked as boot) as I tried the solution from other posts.

Restoring MBR using Boot-repair for the first time, I was able to resume Windows (hibernation), but after shutdown I was no more able to boot in Windows. In that case, I think the Intel Rapid Start it was used as it for hibernation. Thus, I'm pretty sure that this technology is messing up the grub and booting as Boot-repair reports:

```
============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 1 for (,msdos5)/boot/grub.
 => Windows 7/8/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

(sdb is the 32GB SSD).
```

As a last chance, I've even tried restoring the Dell factory image, but besides wiping my Windows, it didn't help at all.

Right now, I am out of solutions. If somebody has other ideas to try, it will be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Might be you want to try manual edit the **grub.cfg** while waiting for other professional to answer your question.

Below are my Windows 7 entry in the **grub.cfg**, I hope that can be a reference for you when editing:

```
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-D4665DF6665DD9B6' {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  D4665DF6665DD9B6
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D4665DF6665DD9B6
fi
chainloader +1
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I've already add manually the menu entry:
menuentry "windows 7.3"{
 set root='(hd0,3)'
 search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set 36ECF4D1ECF48C7D
 drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
 chainloader +1
}

Anyway, I'll try to add yours with the necessary updates for sda3.


One issue seems to be that grub doesn't see the Windows installation even if I disabled from BIOS the Inter Rapid Start and set AHCI...

Answer (score 0):

can you mount sda2 or sda3?

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2
```

can you see any of the nodes sda2 and sda3 in the /dev directory?

```
ls /dev/sda*
```

if not, try:

```
sudo apt-get install dmraid
dmraid -an
dmraid -si
dmraid -E -r
sudo update-grub
```

reboot

Comment: Yes, it was just for the pastebin, I ran it several times without effect.
Also, update-grub :


Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
done